# JavaScript error: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

I am working on a SPA static web application. I am basically loading a script from a different domain before other scripts are loaded. It looks something like this.

```
<script src="https://public.something.com/javascripts/api/something-2.min.js"></script>
```

When I open the page in the browser, I got the following JavaScript errors/ warnings in the console.

```
[Report Only] Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src * blob:".
```

[image]

As an attempt to fix it. I put in the following HTML meta tag in the header.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="font-src 'self' data: http://*; default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* https://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
```

But I'm still getting the error. It seems like it is within the script itself that my site is referencing. How can I fix it?

Comment: `[Report Only]` - so it's really a warning not an error - does your server issue a `Content-Security-Policy` header?

Comment: It is just a static page. How can I make it go away?

Comment: a static page is still served by a server - but you can make it go away by overriding the `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only` header - seeing as the console is reporting `report only` violations

Comment: Still Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only does not make it goes away. It seems like the script that is being referenced is overriding it.

Comment: *the script that is being referenced is overriding it* - what does this mean? Check the response headers **your** server sends for your **main** page (I guess it's a SPA so there is only one html page) - is there a `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only` header?